# CPU Usage percent from linux server

Tags: linux, python-3.x

I want to get CPU Usage percent from linux server, I connected with my linux server from python with

```
shell = spur.SshShell(hostname="ip", username="root", password="password", missing_host_key=spur.ssh.MissingHostKey.accept)
```

And i have no clue what to do now, can anyone help ? Thanks !

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [psutil](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil) library to get system information like CPU usage.

Comment: not on a remote server. At least, not without running a python script on the remote server.

Comment: Is there any other option to get cpu usage form server, I googled it but didnt found anything, I